# how to specified color in plot from matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have player data from fifa 19. It has Composure, Penalties ability, and Nationality. I would like to plot in a figure with X axis is Composure and Y axis is Penalties ability, but i would like to color it if the player from some nationality. I have this code:

```
import pandas
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df= pandas.read_csv('fifa19.csv')

n= len(df)
x=[]
y=[]
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
j=0
for i in range(n):
   if(not math.isnan(df['Composure'][i])
       and not math.isnan(df['Penalties'][i])):
       x.append(df['Composure'][i])
       y.append(df['Penalties'][i])
   if(df['Nationality'][i]=='Brazil'): #it supposed to be blue if the nationality is brazil else is default(correct me if i'm wrong)
       ax.plot(x, y, 'o', color='blue')

ax.set_xlabel('Composure attribute')
ax.set_ylabel('Penalties attribute')
fig.show()
```

[But it all turned to blue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1tro.png) 
I have tried to change the loop like this:

```
if(df['Nationality'][i]=='Brazil'): 
        ax.plot(x[i], y[i], 'o', color='blue')
```

But it says 'IndexError: list index out of range'. Any idea how to color it using plot? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you only drawing if they are from Brazil? Otherwise, you could write an else statement and select the desired color

Comment: I've tried for that but the error is still the same, IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score -1):

use this code

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import style

plt.title("Natitk")
plt.plot([1,4,7],[3,4,5],linewidth=4, Label="first", color="yellow")
plt.plot([5,4,7],[2,6,8],linewidth=4, Label="second")

plt.legend()

plt.xlabel("x")
style.use("ggplot")
plt.ylabel("y")
```

store yellow in a variable and then use if statement